# Sending and receiving email messages to localhost with a specific domain name

Tags: email, localhost, hosts-file, hostname

I need to be able to send email messages to `localhost` by using another hostname/domain name that `localhost`.

Thus instead of `me@localhost` I need something such as `me@domain.something`. (I require a dot within the email address for integration testing purposes).

Can someone please provide advice and guidance? Should I edit the `hosts` file? If so how and what else is required in order to receive email messages to that specific domain?

Comment: This is a good question. What sort of mail processing software are you using for the `@localhost` emails?

Comment: Eh eh. That's another issue I have. I use Hoodiecrow as a mail server (http://hoodiecrow.com/). I am not sure how to configure it to take into account the modification to `hosts`...

Comment: That might be worth a second question...

Comment: Done! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828525/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes editing your host file should be enough.

Here is an example of my `/etc/hosts` file with `domain.something` pointing back to `127.0.0.1`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       My-Computer
127.0.0.1       domain.something
```

Now if I perform `ping domain.something`:

```
user@My-Computer:~$ ping domain.something
PING domain.something (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.023 ms
^C
--- domain.something ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.021/0.032/0.053/0.014 ms
```

`domain.something` now points back to `localhost`.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Thanks. Does this require to restart some service before it is taken into account?

Comment: @baleto On my Ubuntu 15.10 system no restart was required. However, it probably wouldn't hurt to do so.